# Installing SQL Server 2008 SP2 fails in 2003 cluster setup

Tags: windows-server-2003, sql-server-2008, windows-cluster

When I try to install SP2 (or simply "repair" the SQL Server installation), the dependency check finds the following problem:

```
Rule "Not clustered or the cluster service is up and online." failed.

The machine is clustered, but the cluster is not online or cannot be accessed from one of its nodes. To continue determine why the cluster is not online and rerun setup instead of rerunning the rule since the rule can no longer detect a cluster environment correctly.
```

Now indeed the server is part of a two-node cluster. But the cluster is working and this happens whether my server is the active or the passive node and whether cluster services are running or not.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This can be fixed by running the following commands from an administrative command prompt.

Locate this directory: `%systemroot%\system32\wbem`

Then run these commands in sequence & restart your setup.

```
regsvr32 cluswmi.dll
mofcomp.exe ClusWMI.mof
```

Comment: I cannot verify this any more but it sounds good. What do I do? Accept it or upvote it?

Answer (score 0):

When installing, upgrading, removing, or in fact performing any operations on MS cluster-aware software, you should perform these activities on the ***cluster*** - never on individual nodes.

Connect to the cluster VIP and configure SQL server from there.

Comment: Wouldn't the effect simply be that I would be doing the task on the active node? It already fails there.

Comment: Not even close. Cluster-aware software installations need the Quorum, and in fact install key data there.

Comment: It's a two-node cluster. Both boxes give the same error. Where do you want me to install the update if not on both nodes?

Comment: Connecting to the cluster VIP ultimately connects to the active node and we are getting the error described above.

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc719001%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

This Microsoft document (admittedly about Windows 2008) claims that service pack upgrades should be done on individual notes:

"You might not want to shut down the whole system for routine head node maintenance (for example, applying a service pack or hotfix, upgrading hardware, or updating an application)."